# Change server time on GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to change server time on a Google App Engine python application? If so how would I do that? (Google have not provided me with useful results)

Comment: By the means of all the `-1`s I understand this is not a legitimate question, and it should be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the system timezone in GAE, and as [noted in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time):

> App Engine clock times are always expressed in coordinated universal time (UTC). This becomes relevant if you use the current date or time (`datetime.datetime.now()`) as a value...

So to be safe you should stick to this convention yourself and make the conversion to your end-user timezone when needed.

Comment: @MeLight - No, it does not. If your code depends on a system clock, you are definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm gathering time based data, and now I want to switch the clock so it matches our local time instead of going through the whole codebase and manually offsetting the `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: I have time based data too, and I find the best practice for me is always use epoch as timestamp.